# How to find out latest Node.js version Google Cloud supports?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using Node version 10.x locally, and Google Cloud's documents are dated 2016 and node version 6.x. Is there a way to find out what latest node version they support? For example Google Cloud Storage, PubSub and Vision.

GC documents are not well-organized, you have to do easter-egg hunt and still don't know if this is the latest. For example, [Setting up environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/setting-up-environment) says version 8, but Vision says 6 somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest version of Node.js to use [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries) as it is instructed [Setting Up a Node.js Development Environment](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/setup#install_nodejs_and_npm_node_package_manager) guide. [Google App Engine flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#nodejs_version) environment also aims the latest Node.js version. The reason you are getting confuse is [Google App Engine standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#nodejs_version) environment which uses the latest release of Node.js version 8.